# Get number of trailing slashes in a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

is there a way in Perl to get a number of trailing slashes in a given string, ideally in one line? For example, if the string is `abc\\\`, it would return `3`.

I know how to do it on multiple lines, but I was looking for a solution that would allow me to do it inline, e.g. inside the if-statement condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some solutions:

- `$s =~ /(\\*)\z/, length($1)         # Use in scalar context.`
- `$s =~ /(\\+)\z/ ? length($1) : 0`
- `length(( $s =~ /(\\*)\z/ )[0])`
- `$s =~ s/^.*[^\\\\]//s, length($s)   # Destructive. Use in scalar context.`
- `length( $s =~ s/^.*[^\\\\]//sr )    # Requires Perl 5.14+.`

The last two should be fastest since they start from the end of the string.

Comment: `length(( $s =~ /(\\+)\z/ )[0])` should have `*` for `+`, or will warn on a string without a trailing slash. ;-)

Comment: `split(/\\/,$s)-split(/\\/,"$s.")` :)

Answer (score 5):

[perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop):

> Matching in list context
>
> If the "/g" option is not used, "m//" in list context returns a list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the pattern, that is, ($1, $2, $3...)

We can force list context by `(...)[0]`, it will return its first element, i.e. `$1`.

```
$string = 'abc\\\\\\';
print "yes\n" if 3 == length(($string =~ /(\\+)$/)[0]);
```

or, to prevent warnings

```
print "yes\n" if 3 == (length(($string =~ /(\\+)$/)[0]) // 0); # 5.10+
```

But, if you know how to do it on multiple lines, just wrap your solution to [do](http://p3rl.org/do) and you're done:

```
print "yes\n" if 3 == do {
    my $count = 0;
    my $char = q();
    $count++ while '\\' eq ($char = chop $string);
    $string .= $char . ('\\' x $count);
    $count
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I don't mark this as accepted answer just because I can't mark 2 answers and ikegami answered earlier. But this works as well, thanks!

Comment: Actually, choroba's posted their answer before mine. Mine, on the other hand, includes faster solutions.

Answer (score 4):

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

sub number_trailing_slashes {
   my ($string) = @_;
   return 0 unless $string; 

   my ($slashes) = $string =~ m/(\\*)$/;
   return length($slashes);
}

# note that to pass a string with three backslashes, you need to escape
# them once in the source string
say number_trailing_slashes("abc\\\\\\"); # 3
```

Comment: Why hide `undef` errors with `return 0 unless $string;`?

Comment: preference I guess, undef has no trailing slashes :)